# making simple metro style menu in html/css

Tags: html, css, menu, microsoft-metro

First of all, i tried googling about this for few days now, i'm just started to learn html/css
and my skills from 1 to 100 are like 6. That's max.
i have this code which works as blogger html widget, but i want it to be kinda different.
this is the code :

```
:root .css3-metro-dropdown option,
:root .css3-metro-dropdown:after,
:root .css3-metro-dropdown::after,
:root .css3-metro-dropdown select
{
color: #fff;
}

:root .css3-metro-dropdown select,
:root .css3-metro-dropdown:after,
:root .css3-metro-dropdown::after
{
display: block;
background: #2b5797;
}

:root .css3-metro-dropdown select,
:root .css3-metro-dropdown option
{
padding: 8px;
}

:root .css3-metro-dropdown
{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
border: 0;
}

:root .css3-metro-dropdown::after
{
content: "\25bc";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
display: block;
width: 32px;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 34px;
text-align: center;

-webkit-pointer-events: none;
-moz-pointer-events: none;
pointer-events: none;
}

:root .css3-metro-dropdown select
{
height: 34px;
border: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
font: normal 12px/14px "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
outline: 0 none;
}

:root .css3-metro-dropdown option
{
background: #fff;
color: #333;
}

<span class="css3-metro-dropdown">
<select name="dropdown-1">
    <option value="0">Client-side Languages</option>
    <option value="1">JavaScript</option>       
    <option value="2">CSS3</option>
    <option value="3">HTML5</option>
</select>
</span>
<span class="css3-metro-dropdown css3-metro-dropdown-color-ff1d77">
<select name="dropdown-2">
    <option value="0">Server-side Languages</option>
    <option value="1">PHP</option>       
    <option value="2">JAVA</option>
    <option value="3">ASP.NET</option>
    <option value="4">Perl</option>
</select>
</span>
<span class="css3-metro-dropdown css3-metro-dropdown-color-2673ec">
<select name="dropdown-3">
    <option value="0">JavaScript Libraries</option>
    <option value="1">jQuery</option>       
    <option value="2">Y!UI</option>
    <option value="3">ASP.NET AJAX</option>
    <option value="4">CoffeeScript</option>
</select>
</span>
<span class="css3-metro-dropdown css3-metro-dropdown-color-ff2e12">
<select name="dropdown-4">
    <option value="0">Guitars</option>
    <option value="1">B.C. Rich</option>       
    <option value="2">ESP</option>
    <option value="3">Ibanez</option>
    <option value="4">Jackson</option>
</select>
</span>
```

and i want to look something like this www.metrominimalist.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<select><option>`, you should try `<nav><ul><li>`, see example http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using select tags with options I would suggest using Unordered Lists (UL) instead.So instead of your selects, you would have something like this:

```
<ul class="primary-nav">
 <li>Client-side Languages
  <ul class="primary-nav__subnav">
   <li>JavaScript</li> 
   <li> CSS </li>
   <li> HTML </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li> Server Side Languages
  <ul>
   <li> 1 </li>
   <li> 2 </li>
   <li> 3 </li>  
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li> JavaScript Languages </li>
</ul>
```

And so on. For the CSS, you use display:inline-table on the top level menu (primary-nav) so the items appear next to each other and then you can use the pseudoclass :hover to toggle the display of each submenu. Make sure to declare a height on the primary-nav UL otherwise it will expand when the submenus are toggled.

[Here's](http://codepen.io/galas/pen/OPpLaj) a quick working example

Alternatively, you could use javascript, but this should do. There are also other methods of doing it if you do not want to set a height on the UL.

Comment: hm... somehov it does not work with blogger.it works with ":root" command but when i change that it looks ugly. it becomes like semi-transparent...